# Getting children function recursive

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
function getitemfalse(){
    $this.items = $this.users.filter( function(item) {
    if(item.status === false ) {
        return item;
        if( item.children.length > 0 ){
            item.children = getchildrem(item.children, false);
        }
    } });        
},

getchildrem(node, status){
    $children = node.filter( function(item) {
    if(item.status === status ) {
        return item;
        if( item.children.length > 0 ){
            item.children = getchildrem(item.children, status);
        }
    }});      
    return $children;     
},
```

I would like it to loop through all children's children, etc (not just the top level).
But I'm unclear on how I refer to the current child if I make that switch? I would no longer have to clarify the index position of the child. Any suggestions?

What am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/gerarca/f2nue6p4/

Comment: Those `if` statements after the `return item;` in both functions will never execute, `return` immediately leaves the function then & there.

Comment: I'd start by indenting the code properly.

Comment: do you mean return item; ??? it wrong

Comment: the way you are using the filter function is wrong - it shouldn't return the item, it should return a bool as to whether it matches the condition for being filtered - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#affecting_initial_array_modifying_appending_and_deleting

Comment: What does the data structure look like and what output are you expecting?

Comment: link code https://jsfiddle.net/gerarca/f2nue6p4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how your input look like. But make your function recursive to achieve the result.

See the Snippet below for flat output:

```js
let users = [{name: "1", status: false, children: null}, {name: "2", status: false, children: null}, {name: "3", status: true, children: [{name: "5", status: false, children: null}]}, {name: "4", status: true, children: null}];
let items = [];

function getItem(_users, _status){
  _users.forEach(_user=>{
    if(_user.status!=_status && _user.children && _user.children.length > 0){
      getItem(_user.children, _status);
    }else if(_user.status==_status){
      //_user.children = null;  //You can make it null if you dont want children
      items.push(_user);
    }
  });
  
  return items;
}

console.log(getItem(users, false));
```

You can test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/tmcf3q4k/1/) also

**EDIT 1**

See the Snippet below for nested output:

```js
let users = [   
    {
        name: "1", 
        status: false, 
        children: [
            {
                name: "5", 
                status: true, 
                children:null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "2", 
        status: true, 
        children: [
            {
                name: "6", 
                status: false, 
                children:null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "3", 
        status: false, 
        children: [
            {
                name: "7", 
                status: true, 
                children:[
                    {
                        name: "9", 
                        status: false, 
                        children:null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "4", 
        status: false, 
        children: [
            {
                name: "8", 
                status: false, 
                children:[
                    {
                        name: "10", 
                        status: true, 
                        children:null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
let items = [];

function getItem(_parent, _users, _status){
    _users.forEach(_user=>{
    if(_user.status == _status){
      let newUser = Object.create(_user, {});
      newUser.children = [];
        _parent.push(newUser);
      if(_user.children && _user.children.length > 0){
        getItem(newUser.children, _user.children, _status);
      }
    }
  });
  
  return items;
}

console.log(getItem(items, users, false));
```

You can test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/frad3cs0/) also

Comment: you code work very well, but mine not, link https://jsfiddle.net/gerarca/f2nue6p4/

Comment: Yes, and the reason is you are getting children as well.. if you uncomment one of line in my code `_user.children = null` then you will see you are getting actual output. By the way my code will give you flat output

Comment: I tested your code with my array and not work  very well, it's because my array have grandchildren

Comment: can you share your desired output? you want flatten output or nested ouput?

Comment: Did you see the structure of my arrangement? ..... well, I want to obtain the same structure, but with the users with status in true

Comment: so what will happen if you are looking for status `true` and parent node has status `false` but one of (or more) its children has status `true`?

Comment: if one parent has status false, it's discarded

Comment: @Jonhwick - I have updated the answer snippet as well as new JSFiddle. Let me know that's what you were looking for!

Comment: Shah you are amazing!!!! since last night I'm studing your code!!! it's work perfectly!! thanks so much!!